# Array comprehensions in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I heard somewhere that Node.JS has a lot of EcmaScript 6 features. It seems that array comprehensions are not there by default.

Does Node.JS have array comprehensions? If so, how can I enable them?

Comment: no it doesn't. but if you run node at the command line, type `var a = [];` then `a.` and hit tab, you have a good starting place.

Comment: You can write list comprehensions in Coffeescript http://coffeescript.org/ which compiles to very unreadable javascript. Obviously the point of comprehensions is really syntactic sugar though, so it would stand to reason you might find Coffeescript attractive too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think V8 (the JavaScript engine used by NodeJS) supports array comprehensions yet, at least not according to [this issue report](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=890). The V8 project member there seems to be saying that until they're actually standardized, they're not a priority.

Comment: I can speakb specifically to this feature, but if the V8 engine did support it you might find a flag to enable it by running node --help

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Spider-node](http://canuckistani.ca/blog/2011/06/07/spidernode-let-yield-and-array-comprehensions-in-node-js/)... It's basically node, using mozila's spider monkey instead of google's v8.